# MapboxGL JS fill-extrusion outline

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I checked the API doc, there seems to be no fill-extrusion-outline property exist. Basically is to change the outline color of the 3D extrusion. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

No, sorry, Mapbox GL does not support fill-extrusion-outlines. There is no good way to do this.